# Groovy Maven Plugins

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, groovy, gmaven-plugin

I am trying to run Spock tests and perhaps some Groovy scripts, currently for a Groovy app, but in future for Java projects as well.

I am really confused about which plugins should be used and how to best configure them, aka least amount of code.

I found numerous articles showing Maven XML settings for `gmaven-plugin`, `gmaven-runtime` and `groovy-eclipse` plugin, which seems like it works under IDEA as well.
I have been using Eclipse for a while and now am trying out IDEA Community Edition.
One of the confusions stems from the fact that I was able to add following dependency to my POM, in addition to having Gmaven in  section.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
<artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I understand that the question is a bit vague... but so is documentation on the matter :)

Comment: Could you tell use what you like to achieve? Write groovy code?, Write tests or what would you like to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fully Maven-Groovy projects read this post [Building your Groovy 2.0 projects with Maven](http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/building-your-groovy-2-0-projects-with-maven)

---

I have sample project with Maven, Java and Spock tests. There is one requirement here. Spock tests needs to have names like  `FooTest.groovy`.

My configuration looks like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
        <source/>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-2.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Fully working project is here: https://github.com/mariuszs/java-spock-test-sample

Comment: I tried using you pom, but I get an error: "Dependency '''org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-2.0:1.5''' not found".
Removing the dependency solved the issue. I will suggest an edit on your solution.

Comment: Maybe problem with your repository? http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-2.0/1.5/gmaven-runtime-2.0-1.5.jar

Comment: Did you try my sample project? If not publish full pom.xml

Comment: @DaSh Are you using latest maven 3.1.1?

Comment: I think it could have been me getting used to the IDE, but it works perfectly without the plugin dependency on the runtime.

Comment: This configuration is mostly for maven, IDE has other ways to support groovy :)